# Cover Screen with menu bar OS X

Tags: swift, macos, nsview, nswindow

As I am new to OS X development I don't have good knowledge of OS X components. In my app I need to cover whole screen with view but I am only able to do this when my Menu bar is hidden. As other app I want to cover whole screen with Menu Bar. Now I am presenting View as popover but my requirement is not pop view but cover all view as blur view in IOS.
**My project is in Swift 2.1**

**What I have done**

```
    let presOptions: NSApplicationPresentationOptions =
                    ([
                    .HideDock,
                    .HideMenuBar ,
                    .DisableAppleMenu,
                    .DisableForceQuit,
                    .DisableProcessSwitching,
                    .DisableSessionTermination,
                    .DisableHideApplication,
                    .AutoHideToolbar
                    ])
            let optionsDictionary = [NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions :
                NSNumber(unsignedLong: presOptions.rawValue)]

            self.view.enterFullScreenMode(NSScreen.mainScreen()!, withOptions:optionsDictionary)
            self.view.wantsLayer = true
}
```

**My requirement**

[image]

**My Output**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Solution to me on Swift 2.0

```
    let newWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, NSScreen.mainScreen()!.frame.width, NSScreen.mainScreen()!.frame.height), styleMask: NSBorderlessWindowMask, backing: NSBackingStoreType.Buffered, `defer`: false)

 func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

    newWindow.title = "New Window"
    newWindow.opaque = false
    newWindow.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedHue: 0, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    newWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    newWindow.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(CGWindowLevelKey.ScreenSaverWindowLevelKey))

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create NSWindow with level NSScreenSaverWindowLevel - 1, according to this link it works: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/33048-floating-window-over-menu-bar.html

Comment: i got error on this line,  [theWindowNR setLevel:NSScreenSaverWindowLevel - 1];

Comment: i can't find setLevel, what is it in swift ?
 theWindowNR.setLevel = NSScreenSaverWindowLevel - 1

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not progamming on Swift yet, however that code should be easily convertible to Swift.